# How unboundedness of $\|T_n\|$ will imply that X is not complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I have to show that

> The normed space $X$ of all polynomials with norm defined by
>   $$\|x\|=\max\vert\alpha_j\vert$$ ($\alpha_0,\alpha_1,...$the
>   coefficients of $x$) " is not complete

using

**Uniform Boundedness theorem**:

> Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators $T_n:
>  X\rightarrow Y$ from a Banach space $X$ into a normed space $Y$ such
>   that ($\|T_nx\|$) is bounded for every $x\in X$, say, $\|T_nx\|\le
>  c_x$  $n=1,2,···$ , where $c_x$  is a real number. Then the sequence
>   of the norms $\|T_n\|$ is bounded, that is, there is a c such that
>   $\|T_n\|\le c$ $n=1,2,··· $.

I don't want the proof of the above claim.I just need to know **How  unboundedness of $\|T_n\|$(What is the argument/statement/theorem) will imply that X is not complete?**

Comment: For the exact text see http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/spns/cdm/resources/Kreyszig%20-%20Introductory%20Functional%20Analysis%20with%20Applications.pdf at page 249

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is complete. Then $T_n$ satisfy the conditions of the Uniform Boundedness theorem, and hence the sequence of norms $\|T_n\|$ is bounded, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Considerer $P_n(p(x))=na_n$,
where $a_n$ is a coefficient of 
$x^n$ of $p.$